# php easiest way to make array

Tags: php, arrays

I have string from mysql in this format

> 1.name.2.name,3.name.8.name

I have this

> $arr=split(",",$str);$count=count($arr);

this will make 2 arrays, but I want to write it itemized

```
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
echo $arr[$i];
// when $i=0 here must be 1 name 2 name and when $i=1 3 name 8 name
}
```

this is still right, but now I want inside loop write values from `$arr[$i]`, I need to split them by dott. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any loop

```
$string = "1.name.2.name,3.name.8.name";
$array = explode(",", $string);
var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '1.name.2.name' (length=13)
  1 => string '3.name.8.name' (length=13)
```

If you want to break it further

```
$array = array_map(function($v){return explode(".", $v); },$array);
var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string 'name' (length=4)
      2 => string '2' (length=1)
      3 => string 'name' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string 'name' (length=4)
      2 => string '8' (length=1)
      3 => string 'name' (length=4)
```

Comment: +1 after long time. i was really not got OP question

Comment: but I need to explode that 2 arrays with dott too

Answer (score 0):

Using [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split by the `,` and [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove the `.`

```
$string = "1.name.2.name,3.name.8.name";
$arr = explode(",", $string);

for ($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){
echo str_replace("."," ",$arr[$i]);}
```

Comment: yes that's good idea too, but for my situation I will must use 2x explode not only 1 but thanks :)

Comment: With `explode()` and `str_replace()`, you don't have to call them more than once, even if your `$string` increases by either parts - `1.name.2.name,3.name.8.name,10.name.11.name,12.name.13.name,16.name.17.name` or by number of `.` per part - `1.name.2.name.3.name.4.name,7.name.8.name.9.name.11.name`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using a regular expression:

```
$string = "1.name.2.name,3.name.8.name";

preg_match_all('|(\d+)\.([^.,]+)[,.]?|', $string, $matches);
$matches = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => name
    [2] => name
    [3] => name
    [8] => name
)
```